# Creating LinkedTokenSource using typed HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

Hello i am trying to understand how can one create a `LinkedTokenSource` based on the Timeout property set using the typed `HttpClient` (using `IHttpClientFactory`) extension and any other `CancellationToken`(s):

Registration

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient("someClient",(client)=>
    {
        client.Timeout=Timespan.FromSeconds(15);
    });
}
```

Usage

```cs
public class SomeService
{
    private IHttpClientFactory factory;
    public SomeService(IHttpClientFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    public async Task MethodWithAggreatedToken(CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        CancellationToken additionalToken = token;
        if (additionalToken == default)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            source.CancelAfter(Timespan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        var client = factory.CreateClient("someService");
        HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(.....);
        using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(additionalToken,[DI token])
        {
            var response = await client.SendAsync(msg, cts.Token);
            //can i created a linked token?
            //and if not who gets priority : 
            //1.the token set via the  `Timeout` property set in Startup
            //2.the one injected in the `SendAsync`
        }
    }
}
```

In the case above i want to be able to set a generic `Timeout` for my `typed` `HttpClient` which will be used in many methods.Now i want to know if :

- There is a way to add additional `Token`(s) above this general condition thus creating a `LinkedTokenSource`
- Who gets priority if i set a `CancellationToken` in the `HttpClient.SendAsync` while also declaring the `Timeout` property in
  the `services.AddHttpClient`.

I want to know if i can do composition of tokens and also who gets overwritten (`SendAsync` or `Timeout`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a way to add additional Token(s) above this general condition thus creating new LinkedTokenSource(s)

Yes, you can link as many `CancellationTokenSource` as you wish. Because the `CreateLinkedTokenSource` returns a `CancellationTokenSource` that's why you can use chaining.

You can also link more than one `CancellationTokenSource`s at the same time by using that overload which accepts [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource_CreateLinkedTokenSource_System_Threading_CancellationToken___).

> Who gets priority if i set a CancellationToken in the HttpClient.SendAsync while also declaring the Timeout property in the services.AddHttpClient.

The [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) of the HttpClient's `Timeout` clearly states the following:

> *The same timeout will apply for all requests using this HttpClient instance. You may also set different timeouts for individual requests using a CancellationTokenSource on a task. Note that only the shorter of the two timeouts will apply.*

---

EDIT: Reflect to *How do you extract `token` from the `HttpClient`?*

In short, it is not exposed.

If you look at the source code of HttpClient ([.NET Framework implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs), [.NET Core implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs)) then you can spot a `CancellationTokenSource` private field called `pendingRequestsCts`

In the [SendAsync](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L365) / [SendAsyncCore](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs,493) methods the `pendingRequestsCts` is linked to the given operation's `CancellationToken`.

In case of .NET Framework it is done by a simple `CreateLinkedTokenSource` call.
On the other hand in case of .NET Core it is a bit more complicated. The `PrepareCancellationTokenSource` [method](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs,5777ec9a695c9b3d) contains both the linked CTS and the timeout calculation.

Comment: Ok si the problem regarding the priority is answered , the shorter span will prevail.However regarding the issue of `LinkedTokenSource` , i understand its functionality , i was interested in how do you `extract` a `token` from the `HttpClient`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian I've updated my answer to reflect to the how to extract question as well.

Comment: That is what i was interested in.So it is not exposed.